# Capturing screen properly works only in certain taskbar status

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a program loading an image or capturing a screen area and convert them to simulate color blinds' vision.

The problem I've encountered now is that capturing algorithm doesn't work in different taskbar status that I wrote the code in.

The taskbar of my computer is set up to the top of the screen, and it's locked. I wrote the code in that status, and I realized that the program doesn't work on other computers with different taskbar status. I unlocked it or moved it to the other sides of the screen and it didn't work in the way as I wanted.

To capture a screen area, an opaque form is opened by the main one, and area to be captured is calculated from the position of mouse when its left button is pressed and released.

Also the position of mouse is shown by a label keeping following the cursor while it is hovering on the form. The label stops following the cursor while I'm pressing the left button.

I have no ides why it works like this.. Does any part of my code is affected by taskbar status? Appreciate in advance! The code is copied below.

```
public partial class Form_Capture_Rect : Form
{
    //CaptureRectangular is the name of this form
    private void CaptureRectangular_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
        int height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(width, height);

        Message_Capture.Left = (width - Message_Capture.Width) / 2;

        Message_Capture.Location = new System.Drawing.Point((width - Message_Capture.Width) / 2, (height - Message_Capture.Height) / 2);
    }

    //src: position the left button of mouse is pressed
    //dest: position it is released
    //leftTop: gets smaller value from src and dest, X and Y respectively
    //width, height: size of the captured image
    int srcX, srcY;
    int destX, destY;
    int leftTopX, leftTopY;
    int width, height;

    //gets position of mouse when its left button is pressed
    private void Form_Capture_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        srcX = Cursor.Position.X;
        srcY = Cursor.Position.Y;
        //this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }

    private void Form_Capture_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //the captured image will be shown onto a picturebox 'Pic_Unchanged' of the main form
        Form_Main mainForm = Application.OpenForms["Form_Main"] as Form_Main;
        PictureBox Pic_Unchanged = mainForm.Controls["Pic_Unchanged"] as PictureBox;

        //gets the position of mouse when it's released
        destX = Cursor.Position.X;
        destY = Cursor.Position.Y;

        //when its width or height is zero, the function is terminated
        if (srcX == destX || srcY == destY)
        {
            mainForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            //calculate out these for values to get image
            leftTopX = srcX < destX ? srcX : destX;
            leftTopY = srcY < destY ? srcY : destY;
            width = srcX < destX ? destX - srcX : srcX - destX;
            height = srcY < destY ? destY - srcY : srcY - destY;

            Graphics myGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
            Bitmap memoryImage = new Bitmap(width, height, myGraphics);
            Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);

            //copies image
            mainForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;//whithout this, the form will be captured
            memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(leftTopX, leftTopY, 0, 0, new Size(width, height));

            //show the captured image onto the picturebox
            Pic_Unchanged.Image = memoryImage;

            this.Close();
        }
    }

    //shows the position of mouse with a label following cursor
    //MouseLoc is a label
    private void Form_Capture_Rect_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MouseLoc.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
        MouseLoc.Text = e.X + ", " + e.Y;
    }

    //Delete a text 'Message_Capture' which says "Capture Area" 2.5 seconds after the form is shown up
    private void DeleteMessage_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Message_Capture.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: *capturing algorithm doesn't work in different taskbar status...*, what do you mean it doesnt work?

Comment: the area selected should be shown on a picturebox but it doesn't when the windows taskbar setting is changed. the label showing the location of cursor stops moving while dragging mouse, and the form opened to capture won't closed after releasing mouse button.

Comment: Why do you use three different names `Form_Capture_Rect`, `Form_Capture`, `CaptureRectangular`? It is confusing. The taskbar has nothing to do with the problem. You say that the label stops moving so I guess the problem is somewhere else. You need to provide a testable example to check it myself. In general you are doing too many things (*mainForm.WindowState = ... this.Close();*) with the two forms in the mouse up event. That is not a good practice.

Comment: ah.. the former name of the form i wrote was capturerectangular, and i forgot changing the names of the functions after changing the name of the form.

Comment: if (srcX == destX || srcY == destY){
                mainForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
                this.Close();
            }

and i'll get this code changed as you said. thanks a lot

Comment: Not in the `if` statement but in the `else` one: `mainForm.WindowState = ... this.WindowState = ... memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(...); Pic_Unchanged.Image = ... this.Close();`

Comment: understood thanks

and the problem is solved; when the screen is captured, the task bar wasn't took into account, so the bound of the image to be captured got over screen.. After some test i realized that the problem only happens when the top left part of the screen is taken over by the task bar.

Comment: First I tried to get task bar invisible, but it didn't expand the capture area; then I found how to make the form uploaded maximize all over the screen. And then it covers whole screen including task bar.

It was just a silly problem.. the answer was the size of the form, and whether it covers the entire screen area.